# Spring WebClient Configuration Okta OAuth2

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, okta, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm building an API Gateway which uses Spring Webflux, Spring Cloud Gateway, Spring Cloud Security & Okta for OAuth2.

Here's my RouteLocator, through which I can call my Foo Microservice.

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory filterFactory) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route("foo", r ->
                    r.path("/foo")
                            .filters(f -> f
                                    .rewritePath("/foo", "/api/v1/foo")
                                    .filter(filterFactory.apply()))
                            .uri("lb://foo-service")
            )
            .build();
}
```

This works perfectly fine.

However, since I need to aggregate the results of different microservices, let's say Foo and Bar, I'm creating a load balanced Spring WebClient bean that I can use to make http calls:

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
    return WebClient.builder();
}
```

How can I configure the WebClient to pass the Token on every request the same way as the TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory does in the RouteLocator?

EDIT:

Here's my updated WebClient bean:

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
                                          ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {
    var oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);
    oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("okta");
    return WebClient
            .builder()
            .filter(oauth);
}
```

Now it seems like it is working on the Chrome browser. After logging in on Okta I can access /foo on Foo microservice through Http GET. Although when I try an Http POST on /foo through Postman, (while adding the Authorization header), I'm getting a 302 response that redirects me to an Okta html page.

Funnily enough, using the RouteLocator I don't get any redirection and both GET and POST work through Postman. The redirection seems to be happening only when using WebClient.

Any idea why?

EDIT #2:

My Security config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
                .and()
                .and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter(){
        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        corsConfig.setMaxAge(3600L);
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("*");
        corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction (or the reactive equivalent) 
This video covers it in more detail: https://youtu.be/v2J32nd0g24?t=2168

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Check my update above. Apparently now it seems like the GET requests are working on Chrome browser. Although if try a POST request through Postman I'm getting an HTTP 302 Found that redirects me to an Okta html page.

Comment: Depending on how your application is configured, you might be missing the CSRF header.

Comment: I actually disabled csrf in both my gateway and microservice applications. Would I still have to set that header manually in the WebClient?

Comment: No, you should be fine, you could also be hitting a CORS issue.  Spring Security doesn't log much at the default levels (for good reason).  If you turn up the log level in your application you should be able to see what is causing the problem.

Comment: Added the CorsWebFilter but same result, don't think it's a Cors issue. Tried your suggestion of increasing the log level, and this is what I get after calling the Gateway with the bearer token: [client_authorization_required] Authorization required for Client Registration Id: okta .
Any clues? I'm adding Security config file to the main post, lmk if something is wrong. Btw thanks for your help Brian!

Comment: If you grab the access token, and try to make the request directly to your microservice using curl/httpie do you get the same result?  If so that would narrow down the opitons.

Comment: Sending the request with the access token directly to the microservice works. Only calling the gateway service which uses WebClient to call the microservice, I get the 302.